# Parsing "assured us that the storm"

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

What is the function of "storm" in this sentence? Is "assured" a transitive or intransitive verb? Is it dynamic or stative?

> Typhoon Nangka is coming closer to he Philippines but PAGASA assured us that the storm will not hit the philippine lands..

Answer (score 3):

> PAGASA assured us that the storm will not hit the Philippine lands.

*Assure* is a dynamic transitive verb with the argument structure

```
  [SUBJECT] assure [INDIRECT OBJECT] [DIRECT OBJECT]
```

It most commonly takes a "content clause" (a finite clause optionally headed by *that*) as a direct object; *tell* and *inform* behave similarly:

```
[SUBJ] [-VERB-] [IND OBJ] [-------------------- DIR OBJ --------------------]  
  He     told      us                that he was telling the truth.
  He   informed    us                    that we were mistaken.
PAGASA  assured    us      that the storm will not hit the Phillipine lands.
```

In your sentence, then, *storm* is the subject of the subordinate content clause which acts as direct object of *assured*.